# using AJAX jQuery and php in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-fields

Hi I'm trying to write a piece of code that dynamically shows to user a div if the input value is true (am working in wordpress platform). This is what I came up:
This is the code on worpdress page

```
<label for="inp">Inserire codice fiscale</label>
<input style="width: 100%;" id="inp" name="inp" type="text" />
<div id="yeah" style="display: none;">show some text</div>
<div id="no" style="display: none;">show another text</div>
```

The jQuery code I have added properly in wordpress functions.php is the following:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[name=inp]').keyup(function(){        
    var inpvalue= $('#inp').val();      
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',  
      data: ({p : inpval}),
      url: 'check.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'success'){
          $('#yeah').show();
          $('#no').hide();
        }else{
          $('#yeah').hide();
          $('#no').show();
        }
      }     
    });
  });
});
```

and finally the php code which is in the same folder as the jQuery code is:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'pass';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);


    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

$cf = $_POST['p'];
string strtoupper (string $cf);

$sql1 = "SELECT cf FROM table WHERE cf='$cf'";

   mysql_select_db('database');
   $retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );

   $count1 =0;


   if(!$retval1) {
     die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $count1 = $count1 + 1;
   }

    mysql_close($conn);

    if($count1 > 0){
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';   
            header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);
    }

?>
```

Can someone tell me where am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: WARNING: the code written in this way (the part of sql query) is much weak against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve data for? There are wordpress functions for almost everything, I suggest you take a look at them before writing custom queries like this.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: @AkashK. i have created  a whitelist table with values stored in MySQL database. If the user writes a value in the input field  and it exists in the database then i'll show him a Text in a div otherwise i will show him the other div.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro  i'll take note of that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky okay. i will try to code it that way.

Comment: BTW `table` is a mysql reserved keyword. You need to replace `table` from query to your actual `table_name` in your `select` query. Did you try that? And yes, do consider using PDO now.